# SFML networking C++ client wont connect

Tags: c++, sfml

Currently I am trying to learn SFML networking but I am having a problem with the client (I think).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::TcpSocket sock;
    sf::Packet backpack;
    sf::Thread Thread;
    std::cout <<"Attempting to connect to server" << std::endl;
    sf::Socket::Status status = sock.connect("127.0.0.1", 25568);
    if (status != sf::Socket::Done){
    std::cout << "Could Not Connect to server" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Connected to server" << std::endl;
    }
    backpack << 9;
    std::cout << "Sending data" << std::endl;
    sock.send(backpack);
    std::cout << "Sent the data" << std::endl;


    std::cout << "Client task completed" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is The server code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Server Has started" << std::endl;
    sf::TcpSocket peer;
    sf::TcpListener ear;
    sf::Packet backpack;

    if (ear.listen(25568) != sf::Socket::Done){
        std::cout << "Listerner failed to be setup, another program may be using that port." << std::endl;


    } else {
        std::cout << "Server is ready" << std::endl;

    }
    if (ear.accept(peer) != sf::Socket::Done){
        std::cout << "Client refused connection" << std::endl;

    } else {
        std::cout << "Client connection Accepted" << std::endl;

    }
    peer.receive(backpack);
    std::cout << "Data recieved" << std::endl;
    int num;
    backpack >> num;
    std::cout << num << std::endl;

    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When running the server and client (In either order) The client will output nothing after the message "Attempting to connect to server" appears, And the server outputs nothing after the message "Server is ready" Please help =) I have been stuck on this problem for a while.

Comment: I've tested your programs and they worked correctly. So, my assumption is that your problem is not in your program, but in your system. Are your loopback devices configured correctly?

Comment: Well I am going over this, but I will say the order your running them does matter, your server does need to be up and running before you attempt to connect with the client (regards to your "When running the server and client (In either order) comment).

Also on your `sock.connect("127.0.0.1", 25568)` can you add the third parameter?  It's a timeout, this should give us more insight on if for some reason your client is unable to see the server.